# Retrieve nested objects in MongoDB document with criteria in the parent and in the child referenced document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

Below I'm defining a structure for a user (MongoDB document)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588db8c76b1d3032105a8faf"),
    "uid" : "123456",
    "groups" : [{_id : "1", "uid" : "123"}, {_id : "1", "uid" : "258"}, {_id : "1", "uid" : "296"}],
    "connections" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "user",
            "$id" : ObjectId("588db8e36b1d3032105a9126")
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "user",
            "$id" : ObjectId("588db8e06b1d3032105a9124")
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "user",
            "$id" : ObjectId("588db8e36b1d3032105a9127")
        }
        ]
}
```

where connections are also users.

What are possible queries to have all connections **belonging** to a group X for a user **with** uid = Y.

I'm using MongoDB 3.4. I'll accept either a Mongo Query or a Spring Data like query.

Comment: DB references can be queried by `_id` only. You cannot include `group` part.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that i understand description, maybe it's helps u

```
db.collection.find({"connections": {$elemMatch: {"$id": {$eq: Y}}}})
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: find all groups that have match by $id in "collection" array

Comment: I wanted the a user Y's (identified by uid) connections (user's children) belonging to group X.

Comment: ok, lets try define search query parameters, you wanna find documents by "uid" or "group" or "$id" in "connection" array? what a field be in find query? can you show me example of result what you want?

Comment: The result is an array of user structure (The structure I'm displaying in the question). You can assume it is like a linkedin profile where users have a uid, can belong to groups, and have connections, which also are linkedin users. I want to have connections belonging to a group X for a user with uid = Y.